# Sort all Fields in table HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

Hi friends Help me To sort the table Fields in html

I done the sorting without any issues but i add the pagination for my table it make my sort as difficult. my sort work in 1st 10 fields in table i don't need that

code:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table">
<thead>
                                        <tr> 
                                        <th id="uploaddate">UploadedDate</th>
                                        <th id="workdate">Work Date</th>
                                        <th id="assigndate">Assigned Date</th>
                                        <th id="practice">Practice</th>
                                        <th id="location">Location</th>
                                        <th id="actioncode">Action code</th>
                                        </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td>Uploaded Date</td>
                                            <td>Work Date</td>
                                            <td>Assigned Date</td>
                                            <td>Practice</td>
                                            <td>Location</td>
                                            <td>Action code</td>
                                            </tr>
                             </tbody>
                             </table>
```

Script

```
                    <script>
    function sortTable(f,n){
    var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {

        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);

        if(A < B) {
            return -1*f;
        }
        if(A > B) {
            return 1*f;
        }
        return 0;


    });

        function getVal(elm){
            var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
            if($.isNumeric(v)){
                v = parseInt(v,10);
            }
            return v;
        }

        $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
            $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
        });
    }
    var f_uploaddate = 1;
    var f_workdate = 1;
    var f_assigndate = 1;
    var f_practice = 1;
    var f_location = 1;
    var f_actioncode = 1;

$("#uploaddate").click(function(){
    f_uploaddate *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_uploaddate,n);
});

$("#workdate").click(function(){
    f_workdate *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_workdate,n);
});

$("#assigndate").click(function(){
    f_assigndate *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_assigndate,n);
});

$("#practice").click(function(){
    f_practice *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_practice,n);
});

$("#location").click(function(){
    f_location *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_location,n);
});

$("#actioncode").click(function(){
    f_actioncode *= -1;
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_actioncode,n);
});
</script>
```

help me to sort all the fields of the table in database

Comment: Is the whole table content available at the client, or do you have to send a request to the server if you switch pages? If the latter, you have to sort it at the server.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g9eL6768/2/  this what i add for sorting... here my problem is that 1 page of table contain 10 fields because of pagination. when i sort 1st 10 fields only sorting. what i need is that i need to sort all the fields in table. my table gets data from server.